# What is the best approach for WPF Multi Threading

Tags: wpf, multithreading

I am using WPF Standalon application and at the login time we are loading complete Chart of Account List.

so it will take a time so we were use the thread like

```
            ThreadStart dataDownloadThread1 = delegate
            {
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, (EventHandler)
                delegate
                {
                }, null, null);
            dataDownloadThread1.BeginInvoke(delegate(IAsyncResult aysncResult) { dataDownloadThread1.EndInvoke(aysncResult); }, null);
```

but still we are not happy so is there any way to improve perfomance...

Thanks...

Comment: Which part are you not happy with? The background thread and WPF Dispatchers handling or the performance of your backgrounded task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx) MSDN article on the WPF dispatcher.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the details of what you're trying to do, I'd use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). Its specifically designed for doing work in the background of an application like you're trying to do.